# PDF string to TMP file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using API Gateway and Lambda to attach a PDF file to Smartsheet. The request body contains a string that looks like this:

[image: I'm assuming this is Unicode]

My code looks like this:

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()with open(temp.name, "wb") as file:
        file_content = base64.b64decode(bytes(event['body'], 'utf-8'), validate=True)
        file.write(file_content)
        
response = smartsheet_client.Attachments.attach_file_to_row(1234, 1234, (
        'test.pdf',
        open(temp.name, "rb"),
        "application/pdf"
    ))
```

I am getting the error 'Non-base64 digit found Traceback'. This error goes away when I set validate to False. How do you correctly decode the PDF string into base64 that can then be written into a file and sent into smartsheet?

Comment: The idea is to take the body of the request object and write it into a temp file. I saw similar code where people did what I did to do this minus the UTF-8 part. Their code was something like

`
file_content = base64.b64decode(event['body']), validate=True)
file.write(file_content)
`

Comment: I think it's raw binary, I don't think there's a way to configure this with the platform I'm using.